# Querying count by week numbers date range Over multiple Years

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL that gets a count of item_id's for each week and goes on to select the date range of each week number and returns the count:

```
WITH DAT AS
  (
  SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(ISSUE_DATE - 7/24,'IYYY') YEAR, 
  TO_CHAR(ISSUE_DATE - 7/24,'IW') WEEK, 
  COUNT(ITEM_ID) ITEM_COUNT
FROM 
  MY_TABLE  
WHERE
  TO_CHAR(ISSUE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(ISSUE_DATE - 7/24,'IYYY'), 
  TO_CHAR(ISSUE_DATE - 7/24,'IW')
)

  SELECT
    NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE(WEEK *7, 'DDD')-8, 'mon') AS START_DATE, 
    NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE(WEEK *7, 'DDD'), 'sun') AS END_DATE
    ITEM_COUNT CNT,
  FROM 
    DAT
```

Which gets counts of item_id's that occurred each week. I developed this query last year (2023), so this is the result I was getting:

| START_DATE | END_DATE | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-Oct-02 | 2023-Oct-08 | 56 |
| 2023-Oct-09 | 2023-Oct-15 | 45 |
| 2023-Oct-16 | 2023-Oct-22 | 23 |
| 2023-Oct-23 | 2023-Oct-29 | 32 |
| 2023-Oct-30 | 2023-Nov-05 | 15 |
| 2023-Nov-06 | 2023-Nov-12 | 10 |
| 2023-Nov-13 | 2023-Nov-19 | 36 |
| 2023-Nov-20 | 2023-Nov-26 | 44 |
| 2023-Nov-27 | 2023-Dec-03 | 12 |
| 2023-Dec-04 | 2023-Dec-10 | 19 |
| 2023-Dec-11 | 2023-Dec-17 | 20 |
| 2023-Dec-18 | 2023-Dec-24 | 45 |
| 2023-Dec-25 | 2023-Dec-31 | 87 |

When running the query today (in 2024) and have noticed that it's only reporting data for this year (2024). I realized this is due to how I am converting the week number to a date:

```
i.e. TO_DATE(WEEK *7, 'DDD')
```

which converts the week number to a date in the current year (DDD).

What I am looking to do is get a count for item_id's that issued each week, going back 3 months:

```
i.e. WHERE TO_CHAR(ISSUE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= to_char(trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -3)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

and so, crossing into 2 different years

So, my resulting table should look something like this:

| START_DATE | END_DATE | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-Oct-02 | 2023-Oct-08 | 56 |
| 2023-Oct-09 | 2023-Oct-15 | 45 |
| 2023-Oct-16 | 2023-Oct-22 | 23 |
| 2023-Oct-23 | 2023-Oct-29 | 32 |
| 2023-Oct-30 | 2023-Nov-05 | 15 |
| 2023-Nov-06 | 2023-Nov-12 | 10 |
| 2023-Nov-13 | 2023-Nov-19 | 36 |
| 2023-Nov-20 | 2023-Nov-26 | 44 |
| 2023-Nov-27 | 2023-Dec-03 | 12 |
| 2023-Dec-04 | 2023-Dec-10 | 19 |
| 2023-Dec-11 | 2023-Dec-17 | 20 |
| 2023-Dec-18 | 2023-Dec-24 | 45 |
| 2023-Dec-25 | 2023-Dec-31 | 87 |
| **2024-Jan-01** | **2024-Jan-07** | **8** |

I am not sure how to get the count of the week for both last year and this year. I was trying to use the year and week number to convert to the correct week range, but I am not having much luck and I am not quite sure that's the way I need to do this. Digging around on Stack hasn't provided me with an answer either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `TO_CHAR`, just `TRUNC`ate to the start of the iso-week (which is always Midnight on Monday):

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(issue_date, 'IW') AS start_date, 
       TRUNC(issue_date, 'IW') + INTERVAL '6 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND AS end_date,
       COUNT(item_id)
FROM   my_table
WHERE  ISSUE_DATE >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3), 'IW')
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(ISSUE_DATE, 'IW');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (issue_date, item_id) AS
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-02' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 56 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-09' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 45 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-16' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 23 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-23' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 32 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-30' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-11-06' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-11-13' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 36 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-11-20' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 44 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-11-27' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-12-04' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 19 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-12-11' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-12-18' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 45 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-12-25' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 87 UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2024-01-01' + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 7), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8;
```

Outputs:

| START_DATE | END_DATE | COUNT(ITEM_ID) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-02 00:00:00 | 2023-10-08 23:59:59 | 56 |
| 2023-10-09 00:00:00 | 2023-10-15 23:59:59 | 45 |
| 2023-10-16 00:00:00 | 2023-10-22 23:59:59 | 23 |
| 2023-10-23 00:00:00 | 2023-10-29 23:59:59 | 32 |
| 2023-10-30 00:00:00 | 2023-11-05 23:59:59 | 15 |
| 2023-11-06 00:00:00 | 2023-11-12 23:59:59 | 10 |
| 2023-11-13 00:00:00 | 2023-11-19 23:59:59 | 36 |
| 2023-11-20 00:00:00 | 2023-11-26 23:59:59 | 44 |
| 2023-11-27 00:00:00 | 2023-12-03 23:59:59 | 12 |
| 2023-12-04 00:00:00 | 2023-12-10 23:59:59 | 19 |
| 2023-12-11 00:00:00 | 2023-12-17 23:59:59 | 20 |
| 2023-12-18 00:00:00 | 2023-12-24 23:59:59 | 45 |
| 2023-12-25 00:00:00 | 2023-12-31 23:59:59 | 87 |
| 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-01-07 23:59:59 | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AmYvEKUz)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is you're storing a date as something other than date - then later you need date info, and no longer have a date.

In your first table, you are storing the "date" as 2 columns:
week and year.
why not store it as a single column? ie a DATE ?

This would solve all your problems immediately, and inherently .. and would probably make your logic a bit easier while you're at it.

Consider the following logic:

This is what you're doing in the first query:

(w_d is just a view to "fake/create" some test data ...
the main select just mimics your first query )

```
  with w_d as
     ( select sysdate - level  d  from dual connect by level < 20 )
  select d, to_char(d - 7/24, 'IYYYY') year,
           to_char(d - 7/24, 'IW') week
    from w_d
  order by d
  /

  D                    YEAR WE
  -------------------- ---- --
  14-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 50
  15-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 50
  16-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 50
  17-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 50
  18-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 51
  19-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 51
  20-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 51
  21-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 51
  22-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 51
  23-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 51
  24-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 51
  25-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 52
  26-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 52
  27-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 52
  28-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 52
  29-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 52
  30-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 52
  31-dec-2023 15:11:55 2023 52
  01-jan-2024 15:11:55 2024 01

  19 rows selected.
```

This is what I would suggest:

( ie: trunc(d, 'IW')

using TRUNC directly on the date, and keep it as a date: ie the date of the first day of the week for your weekly range.)

```
  with w_d as
     ( select sysdate - level  d  from dual connect by level < 20 )
  select d, trunc(d, 'IW') week
    from w_d
  order by d
  /

  D                    WEEK
  -------------------- --------------------
  14-dec-2023 15:03:26 11-dec-2023 00:00:00
  15-dec-2023 15:03:26 11-dec-2023 00:00:00
  16-dec-2023 15:03:26 11-dec-2023 00:00:00
  17-dec-2023 15:03:26 11-dec-2023 00:00:00
  18-dec-2023 15:03:26 18-dec-2023 00:00:00
  19-dec-2023 15:03:26 18-dec-2023 00:00:00
  20-dec-2023 15:03:26 18-dec-2023 00:00:00
  21-dec-2023 15:03:26 18-dec-2023 00:00:00
  22-dec-2023 15:03:26 18-dec-2023 00:00:00
  23-dec-2023 15:03:26 18-dec-2023 00:00:00
  24-dec-2023 15:03:26 18-dec-2023 00:00:00
  25-dec-2023 15:03:26 25-dec-2023 00:00:00
  26-dec-2023 15:03:26 25-dec-2023 00:00:00
  27-dec-2023 15:03:26 25-dec-2023 00:00:00
  28-dec-2023 15:03:26 25-dec-2023 00:00:00
  29-dec-2023 15:03:26 25-dec-2023 00:00:00
  30-dec-2023 15:03:26 25-dec-2023 00:00:00
  31-dec-2023 15:03:26 25-dec-2023 00:00:00
  01-jan-2024 15:03:26 01-jan-2024 00:00:00

  19 rows selected.
```

By keeping it a date, it keeps/maintains your year in there, and makes it trivial to continue working with.

ie here's your date range:
I only need to +6 to the week to get the end of the range.
I can also extract the actual numeric week of year at any time via:

to_char(week,'IW')

```
  with w_d as
     ( select sysdate - level  d  from dual connect by level < 20 ),
     wd1 as ( select d, trunc(d, 'IW') week
        from w_d)
  select week as start_date,
         week+6 as end_date,
         to_char(week,'IW')
    from wd1
  order by d
  /

  START_DATE           END_DATE             TO
  -------------------- -------------------- --
  11-dec-2023 00:00:00 17-dec-2023 00:00:00 50
  11-dec-2023 00:00:00 17-dec-2023 00:00:00 50
  11-dec-2023 00:00:00 17-dec-2023 00:00:00 50
  11-dec-2023 00:00:00 17-dec-2023 00:00:00 50
  18-dec-2023 00:00:00 24-dec-2023 00:00:00 51
  18-dec-2023 00:00:00 24-dec-2023 00:00:00 51
  18-dec-2023 00:00:00 24-dec-2023 00:00:00 51
  18-dec-2023 00:00:00 24-dec-2023 00:00:00 51
  18-dec-2023 00:00:00 24-dec-2023 00:00:00 51
  18-dec-2023 00:00:00 24-dec-2023 00:00:00 51
  18-dec-2023 00:00:00 24-dec-2023 00:00:00 51
  25-dec-2023 00:00:00 31-dec-2023 00:00:00 52
  25-dec-2023 00:00:00 31-dec-2023 00:00:00 52
  25-dec-2023 00:00:00 31-dec-2023 00:00:00 52
  25-dec-2023 00:00:00 31-dec-2023 00:00:00 52
  25-dec-2023 00:00:00 31-dec-2023 00:00:00 52
  25-dec-2023 00:00:00 31-dec-2023 00:00:00 52
  25-dec-2023 00:00:00 31-dec-2023 00:00:00 52
  01-jan-2024 00:00:00 07-jan-2024 00:00:00 01

  19 rows selected.
```

The biggest trick with things like this that I find .. keep dates as date for as long as you can .. until you ***really*** have to convert it to something else.

The fixed date "Dec 11, 2023" works just as well as "50" for grouping and such .. so keep it as a date, as it seems that's easier for what you're doing ;)

Good luck!